# Run Asp.Net web application with android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, visual-studio-2012, emulation

When I run my web application with Eclipse in Visual Studio, the machine says that

```
"The file 'http://localhost:18207/' could not be found".
```

If I launch the application with Firefox, IE or iPhone Simulator there are no problems, what could be the issue?

Are there any other ways I could simulate my application running in an android smartphone?

Comment: I find http://www.genymotion.com/ as an emulator great to use. a lot faster too

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded it and it is good for seeing how a website is displayed on the device, but I couldn't run my visual studio application with it, as I can do with iPhone simulator.

Comment: Are you using Xamarin?.

Comment: No, but what I am trying to do is just to see how a website (not an application) is displayed in different devices.

Comment: `I run my web application with Eclipse in Visual Studio,` ??? What's happening here. I have no idea. Could you please explain your setup?